# dynamically changing text in android floating view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

i am just a beginner in android and i am assigned to create a floating view for our android team project, i have been able to create the service so far and now  i am trying to somehow change the image in the floating view to a dynamically changing text but got no idea how can i do it, so if anyone can help me out i would really appreciate it.

FloatService.Java

```
package com.example.justeen.floatexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FloatService extends Service{

private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView floatIcon;

@Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
}

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    floatIcon = new ImageView(this);
    floatIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_head);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(floatIcon, params);

    try {
        floatIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatIcon, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (floatIcon != null) windowManager.removeView(floatIcon);
}
```

}

Here is the update code

```
package com.example.justeen.floatexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FloatService extends Service{

private WindowManager windowManager;
private TextView textView;
private Bundle extras;

@Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
}

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    textView = new TextView(this);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(textView, params);

    try {
        textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(textView, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand( Intent intent , int flags , int startId ) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    extras = intent.getExtras();


    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (textView != null) windowManager.removeView(textView);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Instead of `ImageView`, use a `TextView` in your service.

**2.** I'm guessing you're using `startservice(Intent)` to call your service, since you're not using `onBind()`. Now, every time you need to update your "floating text" , call the `startservice` method in your activity, but in the `Intent` add a String Extra with the text to be updated. Example (inside your Activity):

```
  Intent i = new Intent(context,YourService.class);
  i.putExtra("TEXT","Updated the text in my service");
  startService(i);
```

**3.** Implement `onStartCommand()` in your service. This method will be called every time you use `startservice` like mentioned in the previous step. `onCreate` is called only once.

**4.** In the method `onStartCommand` retrieve the intent and use the extra String to update the TextView within your service. Example (inside `onStartCommand()`):

```
  String textToUpdate = intent.getStringExtra("TEXT");
  yourTextView.setText(textToUpdate);
```

Keep in mind that extending from `Service` and using `startService` makes your responsability to stop the service when you no longer needs it, with `stopservice` or `stopSelf` .

Comment: Let me know if you hit any troubles

Comment: well i followed your steps, and for some reason nothing happens when i click on the start service button

Comment: hey thank you very much, its perfectly working only thing is i am now unable to restart the service after stopping it, but i think i will be able to figure that out, thank you for your help